# R Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid term in model formula

Tags: r

Using the code

```
formula = formula(paste(x, "~", y, sep=""))
model<-(lm(formula))
```

I got the following error:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid term in model formula

I would like to keep `formula(paste)` because x and y are num[1:82].

Comment: Have you looked at the results of `paste(x, "~", y, sep="")`? - I don't think you are getting what you think you are.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. `paste("Y",c(1:82),sep=""))` will give you a vector of Y1 - Y82

Comment: please tell us what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to (1) fit 82 separate univariate regressions (i.e. `x[1]~y[1]`, `x[2]~y[2]`, ...); (2) fit 82 multivariate regressions (i.e. `x[1]~y[1]+y[2]+...`, `x[2]~y[1]+y[2]+...`), (3) fit a single regression with many predictors and a multivariate response?